# Determine responsive image's height

Tags: html, css, image, height

Is there a way to determine the height of a background image when it's being used as a responsive image?
IOW, I want to know the height of the background image at a specific screen-size (but I don't know the actual screen size because that's the responsive part).
I know how to find the height of the image via the actual image file, but that's not the same thing as the image's height within a particular screen size.

Comment: Assuming the `background-image` covers the entire element, you can get the elements height using javascript.

Comment: There are numerous solution to do this. But the question is what have you tried? Let us see your code.

Comment: I was applying the background image to the body of the DOM.